# ruby command line app: how to output a line and edit it from the keyboad

Tags: ruby

I am quite new to Ruby.
I have a CLI in Ruby 2.5.1. as a REPL.

I need to present a line of text to the user, as if it had been typed, such that it may be then edited by the user, and on pressing return, read by gets thereby returning the edited version to the CLI.

I can find no references to doing this any where on SO.

Please help.

Comment: what you have tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: See the answer by Roberto in the duplicate question.